# spring integration sqs outbound gateway

Tags: amazon-sqs, spring-integration-aws

I tried using https://github.com/3pillarlabs/spring-integration-aws project for SQS outbound gateway but I ended up in an error:

```
Cannot resolve the name 'int-aws:permissionsType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
```

I am aware that the official spring integration supports SQS outbound adapter. I am looking for a gateway where I can proceed performing more operations after publishing the message to SQS. Are any of you aware of anything along these lines?

Thanks in Advance!